# Different results in RandomizedSearchCV using None and accuracy as scoring measure

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, decision-tree, hyperparameters

I am using RandomizedSearchCV to find the best set of parameters of a decision tree. The problem is that i get different set using following states:

```
scoring = 'accuracy'
scoring = None
```

The documentation says:

> If None, the estimator’s score method is used.

And the page of decision tree says that the score method is accuracy.
I don't understand what is the reason of this inconsistency?

Comment: Please add a MRE, or we'll be guessing.  Have you set a random seed?  Are you using a `DecisionTreeClassifier`?  Binary classification?  ...

Comment: Yes, for all questions!